# Printing 0 as 000 in c i.e. print decimal to 3 digit

Tags: c, printf

I want to know that how to print `0` as `000` and `1` as `001` in c and so on.

I tried using `printf("%3d", var);` but it doesn't seem to work

can anyone please suggest any method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```
printf("%03d", var);
```

to provide a minimum field width of 3 padded with leading zeros. Don't forget the enclosing "quotes". If you had put them in your posted code:

```
printf("%3d", var);
```

it would have been padded with spaces.

Comment: please also tell the difference between append (a) and write (w) flag which are used when opening a file

Comment: @SnakeEyes please ask another question. Or look up the man page such as MSVC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx